# Huffman m-ary Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

My eyes came onto Huffman $m$-ary algorithm, which is a general version of binary tree Huffman algorithm.

**Questions 1**: Based on,

$$K = ((N-1) \bmod (m-1)) + 1$$

where $N$ denotes the number of vertices we have in forest $F$ that starts initially with a set of vertices along with their weights. But I guess there is something wrong probably where the labels of the edges are from 0 to $m-1$ and not from 0 to $K-1$, please correct me if I am wrong?

**Question 2**: what does $Code(a_i)$ at the end do, specifically, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a code in the alphabet $\{0, \ldots, m-1\}$.  The main **while** loop reduces the number of trees by $m-1$.  (It takes $m$ trees and creates one new one.)  Since the final result should be a single tree, the special first step combines the least number $K \geq 1$ of trees such that $N - K$ is a multiple of $m - 1$.

A leaf in the final tree is coded by the subsequent edge numbers leading from the root to the leaf.